# Constrain a postgres timestamp to "End of day"?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, datatypes, timestamp, timezone

**Given** a table named `bananas`
**and** a `timestamp without time zone` column named `end_time`
**and** *some* `psql` clients have `set timezone to 'UTC'`
**and** *other* `psql` clients have `set timezone to 'US/Eastern'`
**and** the server config has `timezone = 'UTC'` in `postgresql.conf`

How would one write a check constraint on `bananas.end_time` to ensure that `end_time` is always the end of the day, defined as the 23rd hour and 59th minute and 59th second of a **"US/Eastern"** day?

I tried:

```
alter table bananas
add constraint ck_end_time_is_end_of_day
check (
  23 = date_part('hour', end_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Eastern')
  and 59 = date_part('minute', end_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Eastern') 
  and 59 = floor(date_part('second', end_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Eastern')) 
)
;
```

This seems to correctly constrain the column, but it seems horrendously inefficient, and quite unreadable.  Is there a more efficient and/or more readable implementation?

Comment: looks readable to me. You can improve the readability by moving `and` operators to the end of previous lines :)

Comment: What happens when the day passes and tomorrow comes? Should the constraint still hold (and all values of the column, in all the table rows, changed)?

Comment: I suggest you just add a default value for the `end_time` column. But it seems really confusing to set the server config in UTC but the values in the column in US/Eastern. Why?

Comment: Define "end of the day" more closely. End of *which* day? Also, I would approach the task differently to begin with ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### For now

While stuck with your unfortunate solution:

```
CHECK ((end_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern')::time = '23:59:59'::time)
```

That's right, `AT TIME ZONE` **two** times:

- The first instance transforms your `timestamp without time zone` into `timestamp with time zone`. that's assuming you are actually storing UTC times.
- The second instance converts the `timestamptz` back to `timestamp` **at your given time zone**. Now you can just check that the `time` component is whatever you wish.

Cast to `time`, instead of converting to a string, that's cheaper and more robust.

To get rid of fractional digits you could cast to **`time(0)`** instead, but that *rounds* the values instead of *floor* in your example. Instead, truncate  with [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), which is the cheaper method for `floor()` with positive numbers:

```
CHECK ((date_trunc('sec', end_time) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern')::time
        = '23:59:59'::time)
```

#### Proper solution

`timestamp` values have fractional digits and using the time component `'23:59:59'` as upper limit is an unfortunate decision. Instead, use **`00:00` of the next day as exclusive upper border**. It is trivial to enforce *that* with a check constraint.

Next, since you are dealing with multiple time zones, I would suggest to use [**`timestamptz`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) instead of `timestamp`. Internal storage is the same as with `timestamp` in the given time zone 'UTC', but input / output handling is different.

- The timestamp is shifted to the current time zone automatically on output.
- Input timestamps with time zon offset so the values are saved as according UTC times automatically.

[Related answer on SO with a lot more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: And if they decide to store `00:00`, then there is no point in using timestamps at all, is it? A simple `date`, either today's or the tomorrow value would suffice.

Comment: @ypercube: Exactly. Attention to one detail, though: When casting a `date` to `timestamp` / `timestamptz` the *current time zone* setting is assumed. Needs to be offset to `00:00` UTC if that is the intended meaning of the "date". That makes `timestamptz` a bit simpler for the purpose than a `date`. But a `date` just needs 4 bytes (timestamp: 8 bytes).

Comment: Wow.  Awesome answer, thanks!  I believe that the type of the column is dictated by my ORM, but I can probably convince my team to use the start of day `i+1` instead of the end of day `i`.  Good idea!

Answer (score 3):

You may use `to_char` to get the time fields from a single function call:

```
check (to_char(end_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Eastern','HH24:MI:SS') = '23:59:59')
```

Seconds given by `SS` are not rounded up so that should be OK as an equivalent to `floor`

Comment: I'm definitely going to try this.  It should be more efficient because the zone conversion only happens once.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It maybe be faster, but still unreadable:

```
alter table bananas
add constraint ck_end_time_is_end_of_day
check (
  (end_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Eastern')::timestamp::date + interval '23:59:59' = 
   date_trunc('second', end_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'US/Eastern')
)
;
```

Comment: I had trouble before with the interval and date_trunc approach.  I'll have to look at yours closely and see what you've done differently.  Thanks!